# Motion unity script does not work correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script to move the character. The script calculates the mouse click and transfers the character with accompanying animation to this place. The problem is that in order for the character to move to the place of the click, it is necessary to click this place 2 times (exactly 2). I do not know what this may be related to

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MOV_JANPU_SAN : MonoBehaviour
{ 
  private Animator Anim;
  private Vector3 mousePos;
  private float distance;
  private bool ready;
  private bool permission = true;

  void Start() {
    Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  void Update() {  
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mousePos); 

    if(permission) {
      if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Anim.SetBool("START", true);
        Anim.SetBool("END", false);  
      }
    }

    switch(distance) {
      case 10f:
        Anim.SetBool("END", true);
        Anim.SetBool("START", false);
        ready = false;
        permission = true;
      break;

      default:
        if(ready) {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, Time.fixedDeltaTime * 9);
        permission = false;
        }  
      break;  
    }    
  }
   
  void StartMove() {
    ready = true; //Event ("START" end animation)
  }
}
```

Comment: In general using a `switch` for `float` values is quite dangerous ..  you should **never** compare `float` values via `==`! Due to floating point precision something like `5 * 0.2f / 10f == 1` might never be true because it might be `0.999999` or `1.0000001` ... Rather use `if(Mathf.Approximately(distance, 10))` or a custom threshold like `if(Mathf.Abs(distance) <= threshold)` .. `Mathf.Approximately` basically uses a `threshold` of `Mathf.Epsilon` which is the smallest value a float can differ from zero .. or actually e.g. simply `if(distance >= 10f)` if you don't want an exact match

Comment: So I guess actually it is pretty unlikely that `permission = true;` is ever called. Additionally why are you using with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` within `Update` ? In general no matter if `Update` or `FixedUpdate` you should always rather use `Time.deltaTime` for reading the value .. it is correct for both methods as it will be the time since the according method was called the last time

Comment: @derHugo, what about clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the moment you calculate distance is in the wrong place, what happens is you calculate distance at the beginning of an update step, but your mousePos is still the same as before the moment you clicked, so your distance will still be 10 immediately resulting in the first case of your switch, which stops the movement and animation, you should put the distance calculation after the if(permission) statement and in front of the switch statement.